# Regex: Character range is out of order in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am kind of new to Regex and trying to get below regex work in python

But getting

`Character range is out of order`

[image]

Below is the regex

```
[\x{0000}-\x{001F}]|[\x{0021}]|[\x{0025}]|[\x{0028}-\x{002A}]|[\x{002C}]|[\x{003B}-\x{0040}]|[\x{005C}]|[\x{005E}]|[\x{0060}]|[\x{007B}-\x{009F}]|[\x{00A1}-\x{00A2}]|[\x{00A4}-\x{00A9}]|[\x{00AB}-\x{00B4}]|[\x{00B6}]|[\x{00B8}-\x{00B9}]|[\x{00BB}-\x{00BF}]|[\x{00D7}]|[\x{00F7}]|[\x{0250}-\x{0258}]|[\x{025A}-\x{02AF}]|[\x{02C2}-\x{02C5}]|[\x{02D2}-\x{02DF}]|[\x{02E5}-\x{02EB}]|[\x{02ED}]|[\x{02EF}-\x{02FF}]|[\x{0375}]|[\x{037E}]|[\x{0384}-\x{0385}]|[\x{0387}]|[\x{03F6}]|[\x{0482}]|[\x{0488}-\x{0489}]|[\x{055A}-\x{0560}]|[\x{0588}-\x{058F}]|[\x{05BE}]|[\x{05C0}]|[\x{05C3}]|[\x{05C6}]|[\x{05EF}]|[\x{05F3}-\x{060F}]|[\x{061B}-\x{061F}]|[\x{066A}-\x{066D}]|[\x{06D4}]|[\x{06DD}-\x{06DE}]|[\x{06E9}]|[\x{06FD}-\x{06FE}]|[\x{0700}-\x{070F}]|[\x{07F6}-\x{07F9}]|[\x{07FD}-\x{07FF}]|[\x{0830}-\x{083E}]|[\x{085E}]|[\x{0870}-\x{089F}]|[\x{08B5}]|[\x{08BE}-\x{08D3}]|[\x{08E2}]|[\x{0964}-\x{0965}]|[\x{0970}]|[\x{09F2}-\x{09FB}]|[\x{09FD}-\x{09FE}]|[\x{0A76}]|[\x{0AF0}-\x{0AF1}]|[\x{0B55}]|[\x{0B70}]|[\x{0B72}-\x{0B77}]|[\x{0BF0}-\x{0BFA}]|[\x{0C04}]|[\x{0C3C}]|[\x{0C5D}]|[\x{0C77}-\x{0C7F}]|[\x{0C84}]|[\x{0CDD}]|[\x{0D04}]|[\x{0D4F}]|[\x{0D58}-\x{0D5E}]|[\x{0D70}-\x{0D79}]|[\x{0D81}]|[\x{0DF4}]|[\x{0E3F}]|[\x{0E4F}]|[\x{0E5A}-\x{0E5B}]|[\x{0E86}]|[\x{0E89}]|[\x{0E8C}]|[\x{0E8E}-\x{0E93}]|[\x{0E98}]|[\x{0EA0}]|[\x{0EA8}-\x{0EA9}]|[\x{0EAC}]|[\x{0EBA}]|[\x{0F01}-\x{0F17}]|[\x{0F1A}-\x{0F1F}]|[\x{0F2A}-\x{0F34}]|[\x{0F36}]|[\x{0F38}]|[\x{0F3A}-\x{0F3D}]|[\x{0F85}]|[\x{0FBE}-\x{0FC5}]|[\x{0FC7}-\x{0FDA}]|[\x{104A}-\x{104F}]|[\x{109E}-\x{109F}]|[\x{10FB}]|[\x{1360}-\x{137C}]|[\x{1390}-\x{1399}]|[\x{1400}]|[\x{166D}-\x{166E}]|[\x{169B}-\x{169C}]|[\x{16EB}-\x{16ED}]|[\x{170D}]|[\x{1715}-\x{171F}]|[\x{1735}-\x{1736}]|[\x{17D4}-\x{17D6}]|[\x{17D8}-\x{17DB}]|[\x{17F0}-\x{180A}]|[\x{180E}-\x{180F}]|[\x{1878}]|[\x{1940}-\x{1945}]|[\x{19DA}-\x{19FF}]|[\x{1A1E}-\x{1A1F}]|[\x{1AA0}-\x{1AA6}]|[\x{1AA8}-\x{1AAD}]|[\x{1ABE}-\x{1ACE}]|[\x{1B4C}]|[\x{1B5A}-\x{1B6A}]|[\x{1B74}-\x{1B7E}]|[\x{1BFC}-\x{1BFF}]|[\x{1C3B}-\x{1C3F}]|[\x{1C7E}-\x{1C7F}]|[\x{1C90}-\x{1CC7}]|[\x{1CD3}]|[\x{1CFA}]|[\x{1DFA}]|[\x{1FBD}]|[\x{1FBF}-\x{1FC1}]|[\x{1FCD}-\x{1FCF}]|[\x{1FDD}-\x{1FDF}]|[\x{1FED}-\x{1FEF}]|[\x{1FFD}-\x{1FFE}]|[\x{200B}-\x{2027}]|[\x{202A}-\x{202E}]|[\x{2030}-\x{203E}]|[\x{2041}-\x{2053}]|[\x{2055}-\x{205E}]|[\x{2060}-\x{2070}]|[\x{2074}-\x{207E}]|[\x{2080}-\x{208E}]|[\x{20A0}-\x{20AB}]|[\x{20AD}-\x{20C0}]|[\x{20DD}-\x{20E0}]|[\x{20E2}-\x{20E4}]|[\x{2100}-\x{2101}]|[\x{2103}-\x{2106}]|[\x{2108}-\x{2109}]|[\x{2114}]|[\x{2116}-\x{2118}]|[\x{211E}-\x{2123}]|[\x{2125}]|[\x{2127}]|[\x{2129}]|[\x{212E}]|[\x{213A}-\x{213B}]|[\x{2140}-\x{2144}]|[\x{214A}-\x{214D}]|[\x{214F}-\x{2169}]|[\x{2170}-\x{2179}]|[\x{2189}-\x{2BFF}]|[\x{2C2F}]|[\x{2C5F}]|[\x{2CE5}-\x{2CEA}]|[\x{2CF9}-\x{2CFF}]|[\x{2D70}]|[\x{2E00}-\x{2E2E}]|[\x{2E30}-\x{2FFB}]|[\x{3001}-\x{3004}]|[\x{3006}-\x{3020}]|[\x{3030}]|[\x{3036}-\x{3037}]|[\x{303D}-\x{303F}]|[\x{309B}-\x{309C}]|[\x{30A0}]|[\x{30FD}-\x{30FE}]|[\x{312F}]|[\x{3190}-\x{319F}]|[\x{31BB}-\x{31E3}]|[\x{3200}-\x{33FF}]|[\x{4DBF}-\x{4DFF}]|[\x{4E28}]|[\x{4EDD}]|[\x{4F00}]|[\x{4F03}]|[\x{4F39}]|[\x{4F56}]|[\x{4F92}]|[\x{4F94}]|[\x{4F9A}]|[\x{4FC9}]|[\x{4FFF}]|[\x{5040}]|[\x{5042}]|[\x{5046}]|[\x{5094}]|[\x{50D8}]|[\x{50F4}]|[\x{514A}]|[\x{5164}]|[\x{519D}]|[\x{51BE}]|[\x{51EC}]|[\x{529C}]|[\x{52AF}]|[\x{5307}]|[\x{5324}]|[\x{53DD}]|[\x{548A}]|[\x{54FF}]|[\x{5759}]|[\x{5765}]|[\x{57AC}]|[\x{57C7}-\x{57C8}]|[\x{58B2}]|[\x{590B}]|[\x{595B}]|[\x{595D}]|[\x{5963}]|[\x{5CA6}]|[\x{5CF5}]|[\x{5D42}]|[\x{5D53}]|[\x{5DD0}]|[\x{5F21}]|[\x{5F34}]|[\x{5F45}]|[\x{608A}]|[\x{60DE}]|[\x{6111}]|[\x{6130}]|[\x{6198}]|[\x{6213}]|[\x{62A6}]|[\x{63F5}]|[\x{6460}]|[\x{649D}]|[\x{661E}]|[\x{6624}]|[\x{662E}]|[\x{6659}]|[\x{6699}]|[\x{66A0}]|[\x{66B2}]|[\x{66BF}]|[\x{66FA}-\x{66FB}]|[\x{670E}]|[\x{6766}]|[\x{6801}]|[\x{6852}]|[\x{68C8}]|[\x{68CF}]|[\x{6998}]|[\x{6A30}]|[\x{6A46}]|[\x{6A73}]|[\x{6A7E}]|[\x{6AE2}]|[\x{6AE4}]|[\x{6C6F}]|[\x{6C86}]|[\x{6D96}]|[\x{6DCF}]|[\x{6DF2}]|[\x{6EBF}]|[\x{6FB5}]|[\x{7007}]|[\x{7104}]|[\x{710F}]|[\x{7146}]|[\x{72B1}]|[\x{72BE}]|[\x{7324}]|[\x{73BD}]|[\x{73F5}]|[\x{7429}]|[\x{769C}]|[\x{7821}]|[\x{7864}]|[\x{7994}]|[\x{799B}]|[\x{7AE7}]|[\x{7B9E}]|[\x{7D48}]|[\x{7E8A}]|[\x{8362}]|[\x{837F}]|[\x{83F6}]|[\x{84DC}]|[\x{856B}]|[\x{8807}]|[\x{88F5}]|[\x{891C}]|[\x{8A37}]|[\x{8AA7}]|[\x{8ABE}]|[\x{8ADF}]|[\x{8B53}]|[\x{8B7F}]|[\x{8CF0}]|[\x{8D12}]|[\x{9067}]|[\x{91DA}]|[\x{91DE}]|[\x{91E4}]|[\x{91EE}]|[\x{9206}]|[\x{923C}]|[\x{924E}]|[\x{9259}]|[\x{9288}]|[\x{92A7}]|[\x{92D3}]|[\x{92D5}]|[\x{92D7}]|[\x{92E0}]|[\x{92E7}]|[\x{92FF}]|[\x{9302}]|[\x{931D}]|[\x{9325}]|[\x{93A4}]|[\x{93C6}]|[\x{93F8}]|[\x{9431}]|[\x{9445}]|[\x{969D}]|[\x{96AF}]|[\x{9733}]|[\x{9743}]|[\x{974D}]|[\x{974F}]|[\x{9755}]|[\x{9857}]|[\x{9927}]|[\x{9ADC}]|[\x{9B72}]|[\x{9B75}]|[\x{9B8F}]|[\x{9BB1}]|[\x{9BBB}]|[\x{9C00}]|[\x{9E19}]|[\x{9FEB}-\x{9FFF}]|[\x{A490}-\x{A4C6}]|[\x{A4FE}-\x{A4FF}]|[\x{A60D}-\x{A60F}]|[\x{A670}-\x{A673}]|[\x{A67E}]|[\x{A6F2}-\x{A716}]|[\x{A720}-\x{A721}]|[\x{A789}-\x{A78A}]|[\x{A7AF}]|[\x{A7B8}-\x{A7F6}]|[\x{A828}-\x{A839}]|[\x{A874}-\x{A877}]|[\x{A8CE}-\x{A8CF}]|[\x{A8F8}-\x{A8FA}]|[\x{A8FC}]|[\x{A8FE}-\x{A8FF}]|[\x{A92E}-\x{A92F}]|[\x{A95F}]|[\x{A9C1}-\x{A9CD}]|[\x{A9DE}-\x{A9DF}]|[\x{AA5C}-\x{AA5F}]|[\x{AA77}-\x{AA79}]|[\x{AADE}-\x{AADF}]|[\x{AAF0}-\x{AAF1}]|[\x{AB5B}]|[\x{AB66}-\x{AB6B}]|[\x{ABEB}]|[\x{E000}-\x{F8FF}]|[\x{FA0E}-\x{FA0F}]|[\x{FA11}]|[\x{FA13}-\x{FA15}]|[\x{FA1F}-\x{FA21}]|[\x{FA23}-\x{FA24}]|[\x{FA27}-\x{FA29}]|[\x{FB00}-\x{FB06}]|[\x{FB29}]|[\x{FBB2}-\x{FBC2}]|[\x{FD3E}-\x{FD4F}]|[\x{FDCF}]|[\x{FDFC}-\x{FDFF}]|[\x{FE10}-\x{FE19}]|[\x{FE30}-\x{FE32}]|[\x{FE35}-\x{FE4C}]|[\x{FE50}-\x{FE6B}]|[\x{FEFF}-\x{FF05}]|[\x{FF07}-\x{FF0A}]|[\x{FF0C}-\x{FF0F}]|[\x{FF1A}-\x{FF20}]|[\x{FF3B}-\x{FF3E}]|[\x{FF40}]|[\x{FF5B}-\x{FFFF}]
```

Comment: Please provide the textual regex, not only the screenshot.

Comment: @horcrux added the textual regex

Comment: Since you want it to work in python, please provide the python code in which you use this regex. Note that the screenshot shows another regex than the one in the text version: the number of backslashes is not the same, and the screenshot assumes the regex is wrapped in an r-string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
[\u0000-\u001F]
```

instead of

```
[\\x{0000}-\\x{001F}]
```

In the second regex you are escaping the slash, making the character class literally look for a character among `\` or `x` or `{`, etc. Specifically, the error comes from the fact that the regex engine is searching for a character in the range between `}` and `\`.

Comment: For python it returns error

Comment: Then you should post the python error, not the regex101 one.

Comment: For python ```[\\x{0000}-\\x{001F}]``` gets error

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eoN0tb/1 is the python error

Comment: Then we get `\x The token is incomplete` error

Comment: Sorry, see the updated answer.

Comment: `[\u0000}-\u001F]` returns same error for python Regex.
Are you sure you are running this for python Regex?

Comment: There was a typo, please remove that `}`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/H6eMaS/1